# Unable to build the rocc-template for riscv. Spike SHA3 extension not working

Tags: riscv

Ive tried building the rocc-template to extend the instructions in the rocket-chip but according to the instructions when i try to rebuild spike to recognise the shah extension, i get an error shown in the image attached.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an issue that was introduced in a recent version of rocket-chip.  The rocc-template example has been updated to include a `riscv-sha3.pc` file along with several other changes.  This update is in the sha3-fix branch (https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocc-template/tree/sha3-fix).  The `riscv-sha3.pc` file should be symlinked by the updated `install-symlinks` script.

Just `git pull` in the rocc-template directory and you should get the new version.